# DAX Filter Table To Replace Relationship

Tags: ssas, dax

I have two tables that I'm looking to create a DAX measure from.

### DimProject

```
ProjectID EmployeeID StartDate
5         2          2017-08-01
6         2          2017-07-01
```

### DimEmployee

```
EmployeeID Name
2          Nick
```

I need to return the `MAX` StartDate where the StartDate is on or before today. The kicker is, I cannot have a relationship between these two tables in SSAS directly, because there's already a relationship between these tables through a fact table. Here's what I have so far, but, it errors on the last `EmployeeID` reference.

```
When Placed Into Work:= CALCULATE(MAX(DimProject[ProjectStartDateKey]), FILTER(DimProject, DimProject[ProjectStartDateKey] < TODAY()), FILTER(DimProject, DimProject[EmployeeID] = DimEmployee[EmployeeID]))
```

EDIT:

I've tried an alternate method of creating the join between the two tables. However, while this formula compiles, it can't be used because it states that multiple values are being returned.

```
MAXX(DimProject, CALCULATE(VALUES(DimProject[ProjectStartDateKey]), FILTER(DimProject, DimProject[EmployeeID] = DimEmployee[EmployeeID]), FILTER(DimProject, DimProject[ProjectStartDateKey] < TODAY())))
```

Answer (score 2):

1) may I suggest you to flatten the 2 dimensions? means that you merge the dim tables like this:

```
ProjectID EmployeeID StartDate  EmployeeName
5         2          2017-08-01 Nick
6         2          2017-07-01 Nick
```

then returning the highest date becomes trivial.

2) you can make a non active relation between the two table and in your DAX formula you can force to use the non active relationship with `USERELATIONSHIP`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm trying to avoid flattening the two dimensions due to the downstream changes. I'm unable to create an inactive relationship between DimProject and DimEmployee, because I get an error stating there are 'ambiguous paths between 'FactTable' and 'DimEmployee': 'FactTable' -> 'DimProject' -> 'DimEmployee' and 'FactTable' -> 'DimEmployee'

Comment: Make connection between FactTable and DimEmployee "Single" filter direction istead of "Both" directions filtering. then you should be able to use `USERELATIONSHIP`.

Comment: All of the relationships are set up as Single, but I still can't create a relationship between the two dimensions. I've got a formula that looks closer posted in an edit above if you've got a second to take a look.